# Find out whether Facebook Tab App was invoked by a bot or by a user

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, http-headers, facebook-apps, bots

Facebook Canvas or Tab App is meant for Facebook users to invoke manually. I see a lot of calls to the app in quick bursts in a short period of time (about 20 to 40 in less than 2 or 3 seconds) leading me to believe that these are 'bot' triggered calls to the App.

Is there a way to find out whether if a bot (crawler, etc) is calling the app ?

I am assuming Google App Engine for hosting the app.

(Sorry for a pedestrian question - I am new to this).

Thanks.